# Will my VPS be ruined by Magento?

Tags: hosting, vps, magento

I currently have a VPS for all my personal sites and ones that I 'host' for clients. It is a low level VPS (about 512 ram), but all of the sites currently on there are low traffic sites - load times are very low. Everything is going nicely...

My Question:
However, I just built a Magento site (which also is low traffic) for a client and am wondering: If I host their site, will it ruin the performance of my VPS?

Magento is a slug, I just don't know how big of a slug it really is...

Comment: There's absolutely no way for anyone to answer that based on the details given. If you can give actual traffic figures including peak usage along with a real-number estimate of size/resource consumption for the new site, then someone **might** be able to take a crack at it.

Comment: It's a simple question Mark - not planning a trip to the moon here...

Comment: Asking for peak usage and an estimate of the traffic needed for your new site along with some details about what services your server runs isn't asking you for the blueprints to a space ship. If you want a meaningful answer, you need to provide meaningful details. Without that it's all just a guess, which benefits no one.

Comment: I don't necessarily think Magneto has any *particular* motives against VPSes, however I would not recommend hosting it in Genosha. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: that comment sucked, but i gave you an upvote anyways packs. I know that Magento doesn't have anything against VPSes - but __maybe__ it's out to get their RAM and CPU

Answer (score 4):

Since they're all low traffic sites, why not just see how it goes? If your low-traffic sites are slow for a day or so, I doubt anyone will notice. Worst case scenario you move the Magento site to [another hosting provider](http://www.magentocommerce.com/partners/find/hosting-partners).

Comment: ahh, thanks gravyface - I gave you an upvote. I'd downvote Mark, but for some reason you can't downvote comments.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I was checking to see if anyone else had experience with hosting Magento on a small VPS (in hopes that they would have some advice)

Comment: There was nothing wrong with Mark's comment, mtokoly -- he's looking at it as an engineering problem, and for that, you need data to test/verify.  I'm looking at it a bit more anecdotally I guess: I figure you've got some static brochure sites on there and that another low-traffic database-driven/dynamic site isn't likely to bring things crashing down around you.  I would turn on caching though.

Comment: hmmm... upvote my question and my comment about the moon - and you'll have yourself an accepted answer

Comment: @mtokoly - voting is not meant to be used in this manner. If you've asked a good question, you'll get positive votes. If someone writes a good answer, they'll get positive votes. The opposite is also true. "trading" votes for accept ticks does not help anyone. You should give the accept tick to whoever deserves it (and there's a bonus +2 in it for you as well).

Comment: @mtokoly, maybe you should take a few moments to read the FAQ and find out what this site is about and how it works.